# mysqli database functions set up

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I've been trying to write a function to draw a usernames name from the database fetch he result then return it back to the parent page but nothing I have tried works and I don't even know where to go from here. my old code that I used mysql on works perfect and was easy to put together but this mysqli and all its double parameters and stuff I cant figure it out. so basically I am asking for anyone who knows how to set one of these up.

```
(SELECT name FROM users WHERE username = '" .$_SESSION['username']. "')
```

I want to `mysqli_real_escape` the value if possible so if anyone knows how to set up a function to return a value back to its parent page I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very similar to using mysql_* functions:

```
function get_user_name()
{
    global $conn;

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['username']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        return $data['name'];
    }   
}
```